# Monitoring EKS Kubernetes LoadBalancer service Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have created few services in Kubernetes with type: LoadBalancer. 
Platform: EKS
Is there a way to get number of 4xx or 5xx errors from this LoadBalancer? I have tried the following:
Prometheus - Does not seem to be any metric collected for services with HTTP response codes.
AWS Cloudwatch - Does not show data points for the 2xx, 3xx, 4xx or 5xx errors. Shows other metrics like latency, request counts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved using cloudwatch metrics.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html

Particularly, look at HTTPCode_ELB_5XX and HTTPCode_Backend_5XX

Comment: This works for normal LoadBalancers, but does not show data for LoadBalancers created by Kubernetes Service Type.